# How can I pass a userform's control to a sub?

Tags: excel, vba, controls, userform

I'm trying to reduce repetition in my Userform Code. I've tried writing a sub that sets a SpinButton and Textbox values equal to a defined default value. How do I pass the Spinbutton/Textbox as parameters in a private sub?

Referring to them directly brings up a type mismatch error.
Here's the code that doesn't work:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Call Default_Setter(TextBox_1, SpinButton_1, 0)

End Sub

Private Sub Default_Setter(InputTextBox As TextBox, InputSpinButton As SpinButton, InputDefaultValue As Integer)

    InputTextBox.Locked = True
    InputSpinButton.Value = InputDefaultValue
    InputTextBox.Text = InputSpinButton.Value
    InputTextBox.ControlTipText = "Value between " & InputSpinButton.Min & " and " & InputSpinButton.Max

End Sub
```

Comment: Declare them as `MSForms.Textbox` etc in `Default_Setter`

Comment: This solved the issue. When would I use Textbox without declaring it as MSForms.Textbox?

Comment: When you're referring to a non-activex textbox on a worksheet.